# TikZ -- Line caps extend over/past grid line boundaries

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am plotting a line *L* in a rectangular coordinate system. The coordinate system has grid lines. (I'm using **\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5)**, so the grid lines form a 10-by-10 box for the coordinate system.) The line *L* is ultra thick. I have extended *L* to the edges of the grid lines. The problem is that when you zoom-in on those two points where *L* meets the boundary of the grid lines, the corners of the line caps for *L* extend slightly past the grid lines. Is there a way to plot *L* to the edges of the grid lines, only to have the line caps of *L* be cut off once it meets the grid lines? *Basically, I want L extended to the grid lines, and I don't want anything--including the line caps for L--to go over top of and past the grid lines.*

Comment: Does the solution provided in [A line of length `\textwidth` in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58292/5764) solve your problem? For example, drawing *L* with `[line cap=rect]` option and perhaps removing some `\pgflinewidth`? Give some feedback.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Choosing a *good* `line cap` (like `butt`) can help... but it's not sufficient (look at first blue line). Using a `clip` region is the solution (like with my second `scope`).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand\redpt[1]{\fill[red] (#1) circle[radius=1mm];}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \draw[help lines] (-5,0) grid (0,5);

    \draw[line width=5mm,line cap=round] (-5,4) -- (0,4);
    \redpt{-5,4}
    \draw[line width=5mm,line cap=rect] (-5,3) -- (0,3);
    \redpt{-5,3}
    \draw[line width=5mm,line cap=butt] (-5,2) -- (0,2);
    \redpt{-5,2}
    \draw[line width=5mm,line cap =butt,blue] (-5,1) -- (0,3.5);
    \redpt{-5,1}
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-5.2)}]
    \draw[help lines] (-5,0) grid (0,5);

    \clip (-5,0) rectangle (0,5);

    \draw[line width=5mm,line cap=round] (-5,4) -- (0,4);
    \redpt{-5,4}
    \draw[line width=5mm,line cap=rect] (-5,3) -- (0,3);
    \redpt{-5,3}
    \draw[line width=5mm,line cap=butt] (-5,2) -- (0,2);
    \redpt{-5,2}
    \draw[line width=5mm,line cap =butt,blue] (-5,1) -- (0,3.5);
    \redpt{-5,1}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, all, especially you, PolGab. I'm still the TikZ novice. This solved my problem. I wish I had read about clipping beforehand.