# `shorten` and bounding box in tikz; possible bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf

While working out [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135759/in-pgfplots-how-to-apply-enlarge-limits-to-axis-but-not-to-grid/136230#136230), I found out that `shorten` options do not count towards computing the bounding box of a `tikzpicture`. Case in point:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[shorten >=-3cm, shorten <=-3cm] (0,0) -- (1,1);
        \draw (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw (1,1) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bounding box problem]

The manual *does not* specify whether this should be the case or not.

Question: bug or feature?

Comment: What do you expect as an answer: "Yes, bug" or "Yes, feature"?

Comment: @Daniel: I _hope_ “yes, bug”. I _expect_ “Yes, maybe” :) Seriously, though, if `shorten` is an attribute of the path, shouldn't it be counted towards the bounding box?

Comment: `shorten` isn't really an attribute of the path. `shorten >` and `shorten <` were (I believe) intended only to be used with arrows (which is why they end with`<` and `>`). They fact that the path is shortened even when arrow heads are not explicitly applied is, I guess, an unintended side effect.

Comment: @MarkWibrow I understand that `shorten` was introduced as you kindly explained. However, from the `tikz` user point of view, `shorten` works the same as line widths, or caps or whatever. All the other `tikz`-attributes are counted when computing the bounding box. `shorten` is not _and_ the manual is silent on the topic. Hence my question and my _hoped for_ answer.

Comment: *negative* shortens are features as the name implies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For better or for worse, this is currently a feature.

From Section 12.2.1 of [`pgfmanual`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf):

> At the end of the environment, `pgf` tries to make a good guess at the
>   size of a bounding box of the graphic and then resizes the picture box
>   such that the box has this size. To “make its guess,” everytime `pgf`
>   encounters a coordinate, it updates the bounding box’s size such that
>   it encompasses all these coordinates. This will usually give a good
>   approximation of the bounding box, but will not always be accurate.

It goes on to discuss certain situations where it is *not* accurate:

> First, the line thickness of diagonal lines is not taken into account
>   correctly. Second, control points of a curve often lie far “outside”
>   the curve and make the bounding box too large.

While these specific points don't apply here, the second point shows that control points are considered coordinates for the purposes of bounding box computation, regardless of the actual stroked path's shape.

In much the same way, the `shorten` keys modify the stroking of the path, not the coordinates defining it. If *positive* `shorten` values are used, the bounding box is the same as if the path was completely drawn between the two endpoint coordinates. Then with *negative* `shorten` values, the bounding box is also the same as if the path was drawn only between the two endpoint coordinates.

This behavior is illustrated in the example below. The computed bounding box is the same for each `tikzpicture`, because it depends only on the coordinates used to define the path, not how it was actually drawn:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\boxit}{\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[shorten >=-0.2cm, shorten <=-0.2cm] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \boxit;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[shorten >=0.2cm, shorten <=0.2cm] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \boxit;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]