# A problem with \draw, line weight and tikzpagenodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzpagenodes

I'm having a problem understanding the relationship between TikZ `line width` and its relation to `tikzpagenodes.sty`. (MacTeX2017, updated in the last week.) When I use `tikzpagenodes.sty` as shown below, the resulting line is drawn indented by the `line width`, which in turn causes an overfull `\hbox` by the amount of the `line width`. The problem goes away if I use `remember picture,overlay` but that puts the line immovably where I don't want it.

I'm sure I've missed something basic.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\parindent0pt

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[line width=18pt] (current page text area.north west) -- (current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.15in}

$\uparrow$ With \verb+\draw[remember picture,overlay]+


\vspace{0.5in}

$\leftarrow$ Left margin. With \verb+\draw[]+ $\downarrow$

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[line width=18pt] (current page text area.north west) -- (current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: Example of draw, line width and pagenodes problem]

Comment: I tried using `remember picture` but that does not solve the problem (just checked to make sure): There is still an overfull `\hbox` that is overfull by the amount of the `line width` and the line is still indented.

Comment: when tikz calculates the bounding box it add half the line width on both sides. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130472/2388 for a longer explanation and a `only coordinates are relevant` key that solves your problem.

Comment: Related: [TikZ — Line caps extend over/past grid line boundaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63023/14500)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When TikZ calculates the bounding box, it adds half the current line width around the coordinates to leave space for the lines. However, there is only a horizontal line here. Thus, the vertical spacing is correct, but the default line cap style is `butt`, not `rect` or `round` thus the space at the left and right is added, but is empty.

The following example fixes the bounding box at the end of environment `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[line width=18pt]
    (current page text area.north west) --
    (current page text area.north east)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.15in}

$\uparrow$ With \verb+\draw[remember picture,overlay]+


\vspace{0.5in}

$\leftarrow$ Left margin. With \verb+\draw[]+ $\downarrow$

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=18pt]
    (current page text area.north west) --
    (current page text area.north east)
  ;
  % Fix bounding box
  \path
    (current bounding box.south west) ++(9pt, 0) coordinate (ll)
    (current bounding box.north east) ++(-9pt, 0) coordinate (ur)
    \pgfextra{\pgfresetboundingbox}
    (ll)
    (ur)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the explanation and the fix.

Answer (score 0):

A tikzpicture with [remember picture,overlay] does not take up horizontal space, but it does have a location.  Specifically (0,0) will be located at the baseline wherever the tikzpicture is positioned.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\parindent0pt

$\downarrow$ With \verb+\draw[remember picture,overlay]+

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\draw[line width=18pt] (current page text area.west |- origin) -- (current page text area.east |- origin);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]