# drawing a line the width of the text using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A line of length \textwidth in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58292/a-line-of-length-textwidth-in-tikz)

I'm trying to learn `tikz`.  In this MWE all I'm trying to do it to draw a line the width of `\linewidth`.  I'm able to do this with a rule; I'm able to do this in `pstricks`.  But when I try this with `tikz` the line comes out too short; moreover, it seems to depend on what's happening in my paragraph in a way I'm not expecting (particularly considering where I'm defining my nodes in both cases).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent%
\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\color{red}\rule[-4in]{0.4pt}{4.5in}}}%
\hspace*{\fill}{\color{red}\Huge $\leftarrow$ Struts to show the end line $\rightarrow$}\hspace*{\fill}%
\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}\rule[-4in]{0.4pt}{4.5in}}}%
\vspace{1cm}

Creating a rule:\newline
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}%
\vspace{1cm}

Using \texttt{pstricks}:\newline
\noindent\rput(0,0){\rnode{ps:left}{}}\hspace*{\fill}\rput(0,0){\rnode{ps:right}{}}%

\psline(ps:left)(ps:right)
\vspace{1cm}

Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round I)}:\newline
\tikz \node (tkzlefta) at (0,0) {};
\tikz \node (tkzrighta) at (\linewidth,0) {};%
\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzlefta) -- (tkzrighta);

Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round II)}:\newline
\tikz \node (tkzleftb) at (0,0) {};%
\tikz \node (tkzrightb) at (\linewidth,0) {};%

\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzleftb) -- (tkzrightb);

Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round III)}:\newline
\tikz \coordinate (tkzleftc) at (0,0);%
\tikz \coordinate (tkzrightc) at (\linewidth,0);%

\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzleftc) -- (tkzrightc);


Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round IV)}:\newline
\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt] (tkzleftd) at (0,0) {};%
\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt] (tkzrightd) at (\linewidth,0) {};%

\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzleftd) -- (tkzrightd);

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've incorporated *HarishKumar's* suggestion.  Seems to work when I use `coordinate` (round III).  But not working with `inner sep=0pt` applied to the nodes (round IV).  Also, what's going on with the indentation in *round I* that's not occurring in *round II*?  I would assume that the paragraph break should not be changing the placement of the nodes; but that's exactly what seems to be happening.

Comment: @HarishKumar, I've followed your advice.  It works with `coordinates` but now I'd like to know what happening in the other places where things are still not as I would like.  What's making the difference between round I and round II?  Why is round IV still not quite right?

Comment: I suggest that each line should be one '`tikzpicture`', by putting the two nodes/coordinates and the `\draw` command into a `\begin{tikzpicture}`...`\end{tikzpicture}` environment, or using the `\tikz{...}` form (with braces) containing all three directives. Perhaps consult the manual to see how to do this.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel.  Tried that.  I see nodes now, but don't know how that helps me (other than it shows nodes that seem to have no connection to the end points of the line); they're not even draw close to the position I would expect to find them.

Comment: @HarishKumar, the end of line character only partially explains what's happening in round 1, but I don't see where there's an end of line error in round IV.

Comment: @cyberSingularity, I'll try your suggestion about embedding in an environment, but not hopeful since this problem emerged out of a context where I was already using an environment.  Also, on this point, I'm finding the manual not very helpful and verging on occult.

Comment: @A.Ellett Maybe you should add what your final goal is? Simply a horizontal rule? `\noindent\tikz\draw (0,0) -- (\linewidth-\pgflinewidth,0);`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, this comes out of a larger context where I'm using nodes for points whose positions are not so easily calculated.  I noticed something was off and began to pair things down and then noticed that even for something as straightforward as a horizontal line spanning the page I still wasn't getting what I wanted thus my MWE.

Comment: It was my understanding that you should say `remember picture` for every picture that defines a node used in another picture, or that uses a node defined in another picture. Hence my suggestion of keeping everything in one picture.

Comment: @cyberSingularity, I tried your approach (and I was wondering about `remember picture` too).  But enclosing it all in its own environment didn't seem to help too much.  But I do appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Do you read [A line of length `\textwidth` in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58292/14500)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Node or coordinate does not matter at the point when you use three `\tikz` macros.

*NB: If I say “TikZ picture” I mean either a solely `\tikz` macro or the `tikzpicture` environment.*

*Further reference on `remember picture` and `overlay` can be found in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) in section 16.13 “Referencing Nodes Outside the Current Pictures”, pp. 199f.)*

---

As I already suggested in the comments, `draw` the nodes and you will find that those `at (0,0)` and `at (\linewidth,0)` are just sitting together. (Depending on the line-ending `%`s with a little space between them.)

Take a look at the following example:

#### Code I

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\tikzset{every node/.style={
    draw,
%   inner sep=0pt,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\tikz \node (tkzlefta) at (0,0) {};% where am I?
\tikz \node (tkzrighta) at (\linewidth,0) {};% where am I?
\tikz \node[green] (bignumber) at (40cm,-1cm) {};% not on paper you say?

\noindent\tikz\draw (tkzlefta) -- (tkzrighta) -- (bignumber);
\end{document}
```

#### Output I

[image]

What happens here?

The whole TikZ picture will be cropped (“bounding box”) and put in one (TeX) box. The coordinates `(x,y)` are not related to the physical paper.

Also take a close look at the line end. The horizontal line and the line to `bignumber` are not connected, because the node is there.

If you add `remember picture` to the `\tikz` and without `%` at the end of line (to have at least a little space between those nodes).

#### Code II

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\tikzset{every node/.style={
    draw,
%   inner sep=0pt,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\tikz[remember picture] \node (tkzlefta) at (0,0) {};
\tikz[remember picture] \node (tkzrighta) at (\linewidth,0) {};
\tikz[remember picture] \node[green] (bignumber) at (40cm,-1cm) {};

\noindent\tikz\draw[blue] (tkzlefta) -- (tkzrighta) -- (bignumber);%
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]\draw[green] (tkzlefta) -- (tkzrighta) -- (bignumber);
\end{document}
```

#### Output 2

[image]

This looks better as it uses the actual boxes (that TikZ remembers) to connect.

What have we learned?

1. TikZ outputs boxes, nothing else. The actual placement is up to TeX. (There is a special node `current page`, though.)
2. Without `remember picture` TikZ only remembers the coordinates but not the picture (picture is either `\tikz` or the `tikzpicture` environment).
3. With `remember picture` TikZ remembers the actual (comparatively) placement on TeX paper but still, the box is just typeset by TeX.
4. With `remember picture` and `overlay` TikZ finally connects the actual boxes!
5. Do not use nodes.

But that is not what you are after anyway?

There are a few ways to get what you want.

The **first solution** uses only one TikZ picture. This is typeset by TeX.
So you will need an otherwise empty paragraph and `\noindent`.

Here you can see that TikZ’s way to set the correct bounding box is not optimal as it apparently pads the line additional by `.5\pgflinewidth` on both ends.

The yellow line solves this with `\hspace` trickery but as `\pgflinewidth` is only known inside a TikZ picture we need to use `-.2pt` manually. (The standard line width (`thin`) in TikZ is `.4pt`.)

The green line uses TikZ `\clip` path that is in fact a rectangular (the line has a width!).

The **second solution** actually places coordinates at the start and the end of the line (`hfill`); this is also known as [tikzmark](/questions/tagged/tikzmark) ([Google Search](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=site%3Atex.stackexchange.com%20-site%3Ameta.tex.stackexchange.com%20tikzmark#hl=de&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:tex.stackexchange.com+-site%3Ameta.tex.stackexchange.com+tikzmark&oq=site:tex.stackexchange.com+-site%3Ameta.tex.stackexchange.com+tikzmark)); see the **third solution**. *These solutions need to be compiled at least twice!*

---

The TikZmark macro I provide is a very rudimentary one.
There is a [TikZ library](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tikzmark.dtx) that can deal with marks on different page, provides an extra coordinate system for “remembered” coordinates and and and …

### Solution 1 (one TikZ picture)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill

\noindent\tikz\draw[red] (0,0) -- (\linewidth,0);% gives Overfull \hbox (0.4pt too wide)

\noindent\hspace{-.2pt}\tikz\draw[yellow] (0,0) -- (\linewidth-.5\pgflinewidth,0);%

\noindent\tikz{% do a line width change in the \tikz macro: \tikz[line width=1pt]
    \clip (0,-.5\pgflinewidth) rectangle ++(\linewidth,\pgflinewidth);
    \draw[green] (0,0) -- (\linewidth,0);
}
\end{document}
```

### Output (solution 1)

[image]

### Solution 2 (“TikZmark” <sup><sub>but without the actual macro</sub></sup>)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill

\noindent\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate (tikzleft);%
\hfill%
\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate (tikzright);%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (tikzleft)--(tikzright);

% The following is not pictured in the image below.
\noindent\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate (tikzleft2);%
\hfill%
\tikz[remember picture]{
    \coordinate (tikzright2);
    \draw[overlay] (tikzleft2) -- (tikzright2);
}%
\end{document}
```

### Solution 3 (`\tikzmark`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\newcommand*{\tikzmark}[2][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture, #1]\coordinate (#2);%
}
\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill

\noindent\tikzmark{tikzleft}\hfill\tikzmark{tikzright}%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (tikzleft)--(tikzright);
\end{document}
```

### Output (solution 2 and 3)

[image]

Comment: So this is where some of my confusion is coming in.  The line seems to be drawn (close to) correctly.  But, the nodes are not shown in the positions at the end of the line.  Why?   How can the line be drawn as it is when the nodes are adjacent to each other?

Comment: OMG, this is fantastic.  You've given me a lot food for thought.  I've got to play with this a bit to see what I understand.  But thank you for the extensive explanation.

Answer (score 9):

A `node` will not produce a geometric point even if the text is empty and the `inner sep` is set to zero. To produce a `point`, one should use `\coordinate`. Also the end of line character should be taken care of by adding the `%` at the end. Also, it may be noted that you are defining a node here by means of horizontal dimensions, not vertical dimensions that are fixed with the page. Hence the node position will/can vary vertically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzset{every node/.style=draw}
\begin{document}

\noindent%
\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\color{red}\rule[-5in]{0.4pt}{5.5in}}}%
\hspace*{\fill}{\color{red}\Huge $\leftarrow$ Struts to show the end line $\rightarrow$}\hspace*{\fill}%
\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}\rule[-5in]{0.4pt}{5.5in}}}%
\vspace{1cm}

Creating a rule:\newline
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}%
\vspace{1cm}

Using \texttt{pstricks}:\newline
\noindent\rput(0,0){\rnode{ps:left}{}}\hspace*{\fill}\rput(0,0){\rnode{ps:right}{}}%

\psline(ps:left)(ps:right)
\vspace{1cm}

Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round I)}:\newline
\tikz \node (tkzlefta) at (0,0) {};
\tikz \node (tkzrighta) at (\linewidth,0) {};%
\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzlefta) -- (tkzrighta);%

Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round II)}:\newline
\tikz \node (tkzleftb) at (0,0) {};%
\tikz \node (tkzrightb) at (\linewidth,0) {};%
\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzleftb) -- (tkzrightb);%

Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round III)}: Using coordinates and \% at the end\newline
\tikz \coordinate (tkzleftc) at (0,0);%
\tikz \coordinate (tkzrightc) at (\linewidth,0);% % < put % here
\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzleftc) -- (tkzrightc);


Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round IV)}: \verb|inner sep = 0pt|\\%
\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt] (tkzleftd) at (0,0) {};%
\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt] (tkzrightd) at (\linewidth,0) {};%
\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzleftd.center) -- (tkzrightd.center);%

Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round V)}: You can see the nodes drawn at left and right:\\%
{\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt] (tkzleftd) at (0,0) {};%
\hfill
\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt] (tkzrightd) at (\linewidth,0) {};%

\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzleftd) -- (tkzrightd);}%

Using \texttt{tikz} \textbf{(round VI)}: You should draw it from centers of nodes:\\%
{\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt] (tkzleftd) at (0,0) {};%
\hfill
\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt] (tkzrightd) at (\linewidth,0) {};%

\noindent\tikz \draw (tkzleftd.center) -- (tkzrightd.center);}%

Conclusion: Don't use nodes but coordinates. or

\noindent\tikz\draw (0,0) -- (\linewidth,0);

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Conclusion:

*DON'T* use `node`s when you want a point but `coordinate`.

Just to answer why the nodes are put together despite their defined position: When you use `\tikz` the picture is just treated like a text so no separate bounding box from tikz is provided unlike the `tikzpicture` environment Hence the two nodes are put in a way like two letters by tex.

Using Qrrbrbirlbel's code we just demonstrate this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\tikzset{every node/.style={
    draw,
%   inner sep=0pt,
    }
}
\begin{document}

Using \verb|\tikz|:

\noindent
\tikz \node (tkzlefta) at (0,0) {};% where am I?
\tikz \node (tkzrighta) at (\linewidth,0) {};% where am I?
%\tikz \node[green] (bignumber) at (40cm,-1cm) {};% not on paper you say?
%
%\noindent\tikz\draw (tkzlefta) -- (tkzrighta) -- (bignumber);

Using \verb|tikzpicture| environment:

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (tkzlefta) at (0,0) {};% where am I?
 \node (tkzrighta) at (\linewidth,0) {};% where am I?
% \node[green] (bignumber) at (40cm,-1cm) {};% not on paper you say?
%
%\draw (tkzlefta) -- (tkzrighta) -- (bignumber);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does solve the particular problem I asked.  Unfortunately, I now have many more questions as I play around with this and get all sorts of effects I'm not expecting:  for example, instead of using ".center" using ".east" or ".west" and getting things shifted around.  Oh how I hate learning new things when you already have another approach you understand (`pstricks`).  But I do want to learn `tikz`; so, I dive in.  You answer is very helpful.  I am sure I'll be back soon with more questions.