# TikZ - curly braces end at the same node, but there is a gap

Tags: tikz-pgf

I created a timeline with TikZ. The problem is, that there is a little gap between the ends of the braces that end at the same node. 
[image: gap between curly braces]

And here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, thick, font=\footnotesize]    

% axis  
\draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,0) -- coordinate (x axis) (10,0);       

% time points
\draw (3,-4pt) node(t_k){} -- 
    (3,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$t_{k}$};
\draw (5,-4pt) node(t_k_opt) {} -- 
    (5,4pt) node[anchor=south] {};      
\draw (7,-4pt) node(t_k_opt_impl) {} -- 
    (7,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$t_{k}+\triangle^{\text{opt}}+\triangle^{\text{impl}}$};


% curly braces
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
    (3,-2.5) node(t_k_unten){} -- 
    (5,-2.5) node(t_k_opt_unten){}; 
\node at (4,-3){$\triangle^{\text{opt}}$};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
    (t_k_opt_unten) -- 
    (7,-2.5) node(t_k_opt_impl_unten){}; 
\node at (6,-3){$\triangle^{\text{impl}}$};

% vertical dotted lines
\draw[dotted] (t_k)--(t_k_unten);
\draw[dotted] (t_k_opt)--(t_k_opt_unten);
\draw[dotted] (t_k_opt_impl)--(t_k_opt_impl_unten);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd be glad, if someone could help!

Comment: Use `coordinate`s instead of `node`s to mark coordinates on your path for later use (all starting with `t_k`). Use `nodes=draw` as a option to the TikZ picture to see what nodes do to the placement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `coordinate`s instead of `node`s to mark coordinates on your path for later use). I added the style `draw=green` to `every node` which looks like this:

[image]

The dashed line end at the nodes and the right brace also starts at right border of the node. (You could consequently use the `.center` anchor but `coordinate`s are more comfortable.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, thick, font=\footnotesize]    
% axis
\draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,0) -- coordinate (x axis) (10,0);       

% time points
\draw (3,-4pt) coordinate (t_k)          -- (3,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$t_{k}$};
\draw (5,-4pt) coordinate (t_k_opt)      -- (5,4pt) node[anchor=south] {};
\draw (7,-4pt) coordinate (t_k_opt_impl) -- (7,4pt) node[anchor=south]
                                {$t_{k}+\triangle^{\text{opt}}+\triangle^{\text{impl}}$};

% curly braces
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
    (3,-2.5) coordinate (t_k_unten) -- (5,-2.5) coordinate (t_k_opt_unten); 
\node at (4,-3){$\triangle^{\text{opt}}$};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
    (t_k_opt_unten) -- (7,-2.5) coordinate (t_k_opt_impl_unten); 
\node at (6,-3){$\triangle^{\text{impl}}$};

% vertical dotted lines
\draw[dotted] (t_k)          -- (t_k_unten);
\draw[dotted] (t_k_opt)      -- (t_k_opt_unten);
\draw[dotted] (t_k_opt_impl) -- (t_k_opt_impl_unten);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The differences between a `node` and a `coordinate` can also be seen in [another answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88359/16595), although the topic is very much different.