# TikZ lines not going "all the way"

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following TikZ drawing:

[image]

Why do the lines not go "all the way"? And why does that line appear below what is supposed to look like a water tank?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\def\balloonheight{1.5}
\def\ballooonwidth{1}
\def\vwidth{0.3}
\def\vheight{3}
\def\vpos{-3}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{balloon}=[ball color=red];
    \shade[balloon] ellipse (1 and 1.5);

    \coordinate (bottom) at (0,-1.5);

    \coordinate (vtop) at (0,\vpos);
    \coordinate (vbottom) at (0,{\vpos - \vheight} );
    \coordinate (vtopright) at (\vwidth, -3 );
    \coordinate (vtopleft) at (-\vwidth, -3 );

    \draw[rounded corners=8pt, thick,black] (vtopright) |- (vbottom) -| (vtopleft);

    \draw[fill=blue!50!white] decorate [blue,decoration={snake}] {(vtopleft)++(0,-0.5) -- ++(2*\vwidth, 0 )} [rounded corners=8pt] |- (vbottom) -| (vtopleft)++(0,-0.5);

    \draw[orange] (bottom) -- coordinate[midway] (ropemid) (vtop) -- ++(0,-1);

    \coordinate (current) at (4,-1.5);

    \path (current) -- ++(0,0.3) node (current+) {};
    \path (current) -- ++(0,-0.3) node (current-) {};

    \draw[thick] (current+) -- +(-0.5,0) -- ++(0.5,0);
    \draw[thick] (current-) -- +(-0.2,0) -- ++(0.2,0);

    \path (vbottom) -- ++(0,-0.5) node (belowvbottom) {};
    \path (vtopleft) -- ++(0,-1.5) node (+entrance) {};
    \path (vtopright) -- ++(0,-1.5) node (-entrance) {};

    \draw[rounded corners=8pt,thick] (current+) |- ++(1,1) |- (belowvbottom) -- ++(-1,0) |- (+entrance);
    \draw[rounded corners=8pt, thick] (current-) |- (-entrance);

    \draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt] (ropemid) -- ++(2,0) 
    node[fill=white, draw, rectangle,rounded corners,align=center] (pico) {PicoScope} -| (current-);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For 2): your `rounded corners` value is too big.

Comment: For 1) Never use `node` for anything but nodes. Use `coordinate`s instead.

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before. Your nodes, e.g. `current+`, has non zero `inner sep`, use `node[coordinate] (current+) {}` instead.

Comment: or simply `coordinate (current+);`

Comment: Related/possible duplicate for the node vs. coordinate topic: [TikZ - curly braces end at the same node, but there is a gap](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97887) (and probably many more)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the closing of the lines, note that drawing to a node `(node)` draws to the edge of that, to draw to the middle use `(node.center)`.  Alternatively, as suggested in the comments define a coordinate instead of a node.

For the line at the bottom of the water tank, as mentioned this is an artefact from large values of `rounnded corners` creating short edges.  You can draw each half separately to avoid this and do the filling separately:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\def\balloonheight{1.5}
\def\ballooonwidth{1}
\def\vwidth{0.3}
\def\vheight{3}
\def\vpos{-3}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{balloon}=[ball color=red];
  \shade[balloon] ellipse (1 and 1.5);

  \coordinate (bottom) at (0,-1.5);

  \coordinate (vtop) at (0,\vpos);
  \coordinate (vbottom) at (0,{\vpos - \vheight} );
  \coordinate (vtopright) at (\vwidth, -3 );
  \coordinate (vtopleft) at (-\vwidth, -3 );

  \fill[blue!50!white] decorate [decoration={snake}]
  {(vtopleft)++(0,-0.5) -- ++(2*\vwidth, 0 )} [rounded corners=8pt]
  |- (vbottom) -| (vtopleft)++(0.1,-0.5);

  \draw decorate [decoration={snake}] {(vtopleft)++(0,-0.5) --
  ++(2*\vwidth, 0 )}; 
  \draw[rounded corners=8pt,thick,black] (vtopright) |- (vbottom);
  \draw[rounded corners=8pt,thick,black] (vbottom) -| (vtopleft); 

  \draw[orange] (bottom) -- coordinate[midway] (ropemid) (vtop) -- ++(0,-1);

  \coordinate (current) at (4,-1.5);

  \path (current) -- ++(0,0.3) node (current+) {};
  \path (current) -- ++(0,-0.3) node (current-) {};

  \draw[thick] (current+) -- +(-0.5,0) -- ++(0.5,0);
  \draw[thick] (current-) -- +(-0.2,0) -- ++(0.2,0);

  \path (vbottom) -- ++(0,-0.5) node (belowvbottom) {};
  \path (vtopleft) -- ++(0,-1.5) node (+entrance) {};
  \path (vtopright) -- ++(0,-1.5) node (-entrance) {};

  \draw[rounded corners=8pt,thick] (current+.center) |- ++(1,1) |-
  (belowvbottom.center) -- ++(-1,0) |- (+entrance); 
  \draw[rounded corners=8pt, thick] (current-.center) |- (-entrance);

  \draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt] (ropemid) -- ++(2,0) 
  node[fill=white, draw, rectangle,rounded corners,align=center]
  (pico) {PicoScope} -| (current-); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```