# Drawing over a diagonal line, till a custom position

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following TikZ code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (a0) at (4,3);

\coordinate (a1) at (1.25,0.75);
\coordinate (a2) at (3,-1);

\draw[dashed] (a1) -- node[pos=0.55] (a3) {} (a2 |- a0);

\draw[thick,-{Straight Barb}] (a1) -- node[pos=0.5, above=0.4em] {a} (a3);

\draw[-{Straight Barb}] (a1) -- (a1 |- a3);
\draw[-{Straight Barb}] (a1) -- (a1 -| a3);

\draw[dashed] (a1 |- a3) -- (a3);
\draw[dashed] (a1 -| a3) -- (a3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

generates this output:

[image]

I would like to place an arrow vector along a diagonal line, ending at a custom point on the diagonal.

In the image, the vector should perfectly reach the intersection of the dashed lines. With

```
\draw[dashed] (a1) -- node[pos=0.55] (a3) {} (a2 |- a0);
```

I was expecting that a node labelled `a3` was placed at position `0.55` of the above diagonal length, and so that the subsequent

```
\draw[-{Straight Barb}] (a1) -- (a1 |- a3);
\draw[-{Straight Barb}] (a1) -- (a1 -| a3);
```

could meet exactly this point.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: `coordinate[pos=0.55] (a3)` instead of `node[pos=0.55] (a3) {}`. A `node` has a size, a line drawn to a node stops at the node border.

Comment: Essentially same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99398 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97887 I guess.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, it works. If you want to write an answer, I'll choose it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, same solution as in the linked answers, even if here the initial problem is different (tracing a vector along a diagonal).

Comment: I think the problem is the same, it's about drawing a line to a point defined by a node, but having the line terminate early because it stops at the edge of the node. The purpose is different, the problem is not. Unless you disagree I'll close the question as duplicate.

Comment: Actually, you are right. Ok, mark the question as needed.