# Correctly highlight long ToC entries using TikZ without pagenumbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, highlighting

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23223/13835), I have highlighting for `chapters` in my Table of Contents.

For long chapter names, however, the box is wonky, because `P1.north west` and `P1.north east` do not span the entire line:

```
north west       north east                                      line end
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is a longer chapter heading than can fit in an entire line this is a
longer chapter heading than.
```

This is a problem both with and without the use of page numbers. When `\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}` **is** used:

[image: No page numbers]

and with page numbers:

[image]

My current projects ToC does not use page-numbers. Future projects will, and a solution that works for both would be ideal.

#### How can I correctly highlight a long ToC entry using this approach?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% command to make a hidden node
\newcommand*{\hnode}[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture] \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=5pt] (#1) {};}
% create a node at the beginning of the chapter entry
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\hnode{P1}\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
% create a node at the end of the chap page number and draw the gray box
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{%
  \hnode{P2}\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw (P1.north west)  [line width={25pt}, gray,opacity=.2] -- (\textwidth,0 |- P2);}
  %\draw (P1.north west)  [line width={25pt}, gray,opacity=.2] -- (P2.north east);}


\begin{document}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{This is a longer chapter title than can fit in a single line}
\end{document}
```

---

*My attempt, which hasn't thus far worked*: Conceptually, if I were to implement a solution, I would first check whether a chapter heading will span multiple lines (count characters, perhaps?). I'd then use a pre-determined `cm` value, with a pre-determined node height, as the bottom-right `TikZ` node coordinate.

I thought `\linelength` would work (without page numbers the highlighting is ragged, and in my head my attempt was going to have a neat side-effect of fixing that):

```
\draw (P1.north west)  [line width={25pt}, gray,opacity=.2] -- (\textwidth,0 |- P2);}
```

But that resulted in a highlighting extending far past the last word on the line, and the box is not horizontal. 
The intersection coordinate isn't strictly needed, but I don't know why - I thought I'd have to specify the `y` coordinate.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d use

- `coordinate`s instead of `node`s (see the re-named `\tikzcoordinate` macro), especially if you don’t `overlay` them, and
- a `rectangle` path instead of a line.

Furthermore, the point origin of the TikZ picture is after the word `line` (the same where `P2` lies which you actually don’t need because of this fact), the point `(\textwidth,0pt)` then protrudes into the margin. See [drawing a line the width of the text using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88353) for similar problems.

Thus, the end of the line has to be re-established, this is done via the coordinate `@aux` that is placed with

```
\coordinate (@aux) at ([xshift=+\linewidth] P1);
```

It can then be used to find the line-end on the last line with `(@aux |- 0,0)`.

---

You can avoid many problems if you use the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library where you can refer to a coordinate (disguised as an empty PGF picture) before it is actually defined in the document. This makes it possible to drop the `opacity` key and actually draw the rectangle behind the text.

### Code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft,tikz}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry} % just for this example
\newcommand*{\tikzcoordinate}[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture] \coordinate (#1);}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\tikzcoordinate{P1}\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
    \coordinate (@aux) at ([xshift=+\linewidth] P1);
    \fill[gray,opacity=.2] ([yshift=+1.3333em,xshift=-.3333em]P1)  rectangle
                                    ([xshift=.3333em,yshift=+-1ex]@aux |- 0,0);
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{This is a longer chapter title than can fit in a single line}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

### Code (`tikzmark`)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft,tikz}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry} % just for this example
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
    \fill[gray!20] (+-.3333em,+1.3333em) rectangle ([xshift=+.333em,yshift=+-1ex] +\linewidth,+0pt |- {pic cs:toc-chap-end});%
  \bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\pgfmark{toc-chap-end}}
\begin{document}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{This is a longer chapter title than can fit in a single line}
\end{document}
```

### Output (`tikzmark`)

[image]

[image]