# tikz: Draw horizontal line of some specified width

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I wonder how to draw a horizontal line of some specified length. MWE is given below. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (a) at (0, 0) {Test \hrulefill{}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw (start coordinate) -- (x length, y length)`?

Comment: Also, `\rule{thickness}{width}`, for non `tikz`...

Comment: `\draw(start)--+(length,0);`

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli - Shouldn't that be +(x length, y length) or ++?  Also, its \rule{width}{thickness}.

Comment: Useful informations in [A line of length \textwidth in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58292/14500)

Comment: @JohnKormylo you're right, I was in a hurry... =/

Comment: Do you want the `\hrulefill` (which doesn't take an argument, by the way) to do something here, is that your question?

Comment: Since you've accepted my answer. I do believe that you're looking for width not length, if so, please modify your question to reflect this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `line width` to get a satisfactory line width. This is an example for this purpose,

```
\documentclass[border={5pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
\draw[line width=\x mm] (0,\x) -- (2,\x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: Length, not width, I believe.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., length is determined based on the coordinates. There is nothing mysterious in the length. I do believe the OP wanted the width.

Comment: Appears, based on the acceptance, that you were right (so +1). I know there's nothing mysterious about the length of course, it's just entirely unclear to me that the OP could in any way mean the line width, but I suppose that could be a linguistic misunderstanding.