# How to remove the tiny invisible TikZ picture frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(\linewidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gets a warning

> ```
> Overfull \hbox (0.4pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--11
> ```

On my viewer, I can't even see the "too wide" part

[image]

Of course, it is very difficult to see it, because it is only 0.4pt! However, I don't like having such warnings pop-up, so how to make sure that the line perfectly fits the margin, i.e. set the "`inner sep`" of the "node" Ti*k*Z picture to exactly 0pt?

I know I can use `\rule`, etc. for this, but I have to draw something more in Ti*k*Z, so I use Ti*k*Z in the whole picture.

Thank you in advance!

**Bonus question:** You can see that I am using `\noindent`. Without modifications to `\parindent`, are there any better ways to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58292/14500

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a work-around, but the real cause for this issue is most probably related to the `tikz` environment internals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(\linewidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets fuzz it out using `\hfuzz=0.4pt` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hfuzz=0.4pt
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(\linewidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For more information: Please visit the linked question for which @DavidCarlisle provided a great answer. Also, I think this answer only covers your bonus part `:-)`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However, if I do so, the picture is still too wide by 0.4pt. I want the picture to be perfectly fit to the margin :)) Also, if I fuzz it out, I will miss some other warnings which don't come from these pictures.

Comment: You made the wrong typo in "the". There's a long way to imitate David Carlisle :D

Comment: @TeXnician I don't think I would catch up with him, sometimes, I don't even understand the flow in his answers :D. Did I forget to mention that includes `@egreg`?

Comment: @Someone Please dont use this as a complete answer. It just tries to answer the bonus part ;) I will try to look into that. But as of now, the answer for your remark is quite beyond my TeX knowledge.

Comment: @Raaja I already know it :-)

Comment: @Someone your reply was quite ironical though `;-)`.