# Tikz figure alignment with page margins

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am making some section divisions in a style sheet using `tikz`. However, even though I start drawing the line at `(0,0)` it has an offset from the actual page content border. I also set `\parindent` and it still is not perfectly aligned. How can I force the line to start (and end) exactly at the borders?

Here's a minimal example of the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=14.111mm,right=14.111mm,top=14.111mm,bottom=14.111mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\linehalfhalf}{\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
    \draw [line width=1.5mm ] (0,0) -- ({0.5\textwidth},0);
    \draw [line width=0.5mm] ([yshift=+0.5mm]{0.5\textwidth},0) -- ([yshift=+0.5mm]{\textwidth},0) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \linehalfhalf
\end{document}
```

And an illustration:[image: Illustration of the problem]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This question is related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479079/156344, I think.

Comment: @JouleV, thank you, that pointed me in a good direction

Comment: You should also add a % at the end of `\setlength\parindent{0pt}`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out thanks to @JouleV pointing out this question: [A line of length \textwidth in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58292/a-line-of-length-textwidth-in-tikz).

The following resolves the problem:

```
\newcommand{\linehalfhalf}{\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
    \draw [line width=1.5mm, cap=rect] (0,0) -- ({0.5\linewidth},0);
    \draw [line width=0.5mm, cap=rect] ([yshift=+0.5mm]{0.5\linewidth-\pgflinewidth},0) -- ([yshift=+0.5mm] \linewidth-0.5mm-\pgflinewidth,0) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `\clip` to avoid extra space around your drawing, but I think that a simpler solution is to fill a thin rectangle in place to draw a line :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=14.111mm, paper height=5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\linehalfhalf}{\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
      \fill (0,0) rectangle (.5\textwidth,1.5mm);
      \fill (0.5\textwidth,.5mm) rectangle (\textwidth,1mm) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \linehalfhalf
\end{document}
```

[image]