# drawing thick rounded corner horizontal lines that automatically fill the empty space

Tags: line, hfill

to make it clear, I would like to reproduce this:
[image]

in a way that the lines automatically fill the space on the right and left of the word in the center (as I need to use it for several titles).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you OK about using Ti*k*Z to do this?

Comment: Yes no problem with TikZ, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. I assume, that wide of this line is `\textwidth`, so it is something like this?

[image]

**Edit:**

- For compensating `ident` should be before image code in document added command `\noindent`.
- in definition of command to draw this image the `\noindent` is part of image code, so a care of positioning of `suit` command is not needed anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent\tikz\draw[line width=1.2ex, shorten >=1.2ex, line cap=round, gray] 
        (0,0) -- node[fill=white] {Suites}  (\linewidth,0);
\end{document}
```

or this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent\tikz{\path (0,0) -- node[inner xsep=1em] (s) {Suites} ++ (\linewidth,0);
      \draw[line width=1.2ex, line cap=round, gray]  (0,0) -- (s);
      \draw[line width=1.2ex, shorten >=1.2ex, line cap=round, gray]  (s) -- (\linewidth,0);
      }
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
If you need it more than once, than defining new command can be handy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand\suit{m}{\par\noindent%
\tikz{\path (0,0) -- node[inner xsep=1em] (s) {#1} (\linewidth,0);
      \draw[line width=1.2ex, line cap=round, gray]  (0,0) -- (s);
      \draw[line width=1.2ex, shorten >=1.2ex, line cap=round, gray]  (s) -- (\linewidth,0);
      }}
\begin{document}
\suit{SUITE}
\end{document}
```

Result of compilation is the same as before. This command can be used also in boxes. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand\suit{m}{\par\noindent%
\tikz{\path (0,0) -- node[inner xsep=1em] (s) {#1} (\linewidth,0);
      \draw[line width=1.2ex, line cap=round, gray]  (0,0) -- (s);
      \draw[line width=1.2ex, shorten >=1.2ex, line cap=round, gray]  (s) -- (\linewidth,0);
      }}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]\par
\hfil\fbox{%
  \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{
\suit{Start}
\lipsum[66]
\suit{The end}
    }}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: @stargazer45, see edited answer. Added ar `\noindent` in examples as well in definition of the command `\suite` .

Answer (score 0):

Zarko's answer is much more elegant than mine but since I had already been working on it I present it here as a secondary solution. (I also get `Overful \hbox too wide` when running Zarko's code, probably because of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58292/a-line-of-length-textwidth-in-tikz)).

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\newcommand{\splitheading}[1]{
\setbox0=\hbox{#1}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[
txt/.style={red,draw=none, fill=none},
line/.style={draw=none, fill=none,inner sep=0}]
\node(mid)[txt]{#1};
\node(first)[line,left = ((\textwidth-\the\wd0)/2)-6 of mid]{};
\node(second)[line,right = ((\textwidth-\the\wd0)/2)-6 of mid]{};
\path[Round Cap-Round Cap,red,line width=1ex](first)edge(mid)(mid)edge(second);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\splitheading{Suites}
```

This is the result compared:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that was useful!