# box TikZ of the same width as textwidth

Tags: tikz-pgf, textwidth

```
\documentclass{minimal}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left = (box.west)] 
\node[draw = red] (box) {%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}
    };
\node[left = 1cm] at (box.west) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture} 
      
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to force the box to have the same width as the text above ?

Without using if possible

```
    \begin{minipage}{0.94\textwidth}
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me, but since you asked for a `minipage` with a width of `textwidth`, your box is obviously larger than the text block below. Could you elaborate about what your problem is exactly?

Comment: A node includes the `inner xsep` and the `inner ysep` value. The red border adds by default an `outer xsep` and `outer ysep` to the size of the node (by default half the line width) so that the anchors of the node lie at the actual outside. So your actual TikZpicture is `\textwidth + 2*/pgf/inner xsep + 2*/pgf/outer xsep` wide. (But remember the bounding box issue of your previous question which would have ignored any outer seps anyway.) So: `\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-.6666ex-.4pt\relax}` would be a start. (Default inner sep is .3333ex and default linewidth is .4pt.)

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left = (box.west)] 
\node[draw = red, align=justify,
      text width =\textwidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}] (box) {\lipsum[1]};
\node[left = 1cm] at (box.west) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, `minipage` is removed, but defined is node's  `text width`.

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: What is `trim left = (box.west)`? How does it work?

Comment: @Sigur, i just copied from OP question :-), however  it is described in *15.8 Establishing a Bounding Box (pp184)*  on page 185 of Ti*kKZ \& PGF manual (version 3.1.9a).

Comment: @Sigur See [that post where everything started about trim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58292/a-line-of-length-textwidth-in-tikz).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tcolorbox`. It's default width is `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left = (box.west)] 
\node[draw = red, align=justify,
      text width =\textwidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}] (box) {\lipsum[1]};
\node[left = 1cm] at (box.west) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]