# TikZ drawing with Geometry package

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, geometry

I have the following test document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[
    left=0.500cm,
    right=0.500cm,
    top=1.00cm,
    bottom=0.800cm,
]{geometry} % turning on showframe here makes
            % the thing even more puzzling (to me)
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
        \draw (4,4) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (27.9,20);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The first thing I don't know, and I didn't find any clue in the documentation to `geometry`, is if the margins (`top, bottom, left, right`) relate to the rotated page (because of `landscape`) or to the original page.

Whatever the case may be, I tried both: subtracting 1cm from the height of the landscape page and from the width. It does make a difference, but I still can't get what I would like: a rectangle that's exactly 0.5cm from the top and the bottom and exactly 1cm and 0.8cm from the right and left respectively. The current one (27.9 and 20; I tried other values) just goes to the very bottom of the page and doesn't stop at 0.5cm from the paper edge.

Sure enough I could do it with the page anchors of TikZ, but then I wouldn't know exactly how big they are and how they relate to the margins of geometry, which would be nice to know.

Comment: Have a look at the `tikzpagenodes` package

Comment: Aren't you missing `\noindent`? The indentation is `15pt` which is about 1/2 cm

Comment: @Celdor That works great indeed, thanks. You may make it an answer, if you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first thing you missed is `\noindent` which shifts the whole tikz picture rightwards by `15pt`, that is `~ 0.5cm`.

There are other extra gaps such as `\topskip` added before the first line and `lineskip`. After adding `\vspace*{-\topskip}` and `\nointerlineskip`, it seems the tikz picture is now in place

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    left=0.5cm,
    right=0.5cm,
    top=1cm,
    bottom=0.8cm,
    a4paper,
    landscape,
]{geometry} % turning on showframe here makes
            % the thing even more puzzling (to me)
\usepackage{tikz}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\nointerlineskip\noindent%
\vspace*{-\topskip}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
    \draw (4,4) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (28.7,19.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\noindent` alone (per your comment) put the picture in place, but it left the first page blank. With the rest of your code, the picture is in the first page, where it should be. Mysteries of LaTeX...

Comment: Those guarantee that whatever LaTeX typesets will be readable (ish). There's still Overfull of `~0.4pt` which is the length of a rule. If you subtract it from the horizontal dimension, that is `28.7cm-0.4pt`, you will get the perfect box.

Comment: The `0.4pt` overfull hbox comes up very often on this site, see [Q58292](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58292) and its linked questions (the line width contributes to the bounding box). I'd suggest adding `[trim left=0, trim right=28.7]` to the `tikzpicture`, the lines drawn by TikZ will lie directly on the border then.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I thought it was caused by the right rule.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Although I'm not too concerned about an overfull box by 0.4pt, the linked question was an interesting reading indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If (as I suspect) you are just trying to draw a single drawing on a single page, and not trying to make this part of a larger document, then you can do this much more simply with the `standalone` class:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
    \draw (4,4) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (28.7,19.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which you can compile to produce:

[image]

If you just want it to be A4 with arbitrary content, then try something like this (no margins, but an invisible A4 box).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
    \draw (4,4) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (29.7,21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your suspect is almost right. I do print it out as a single picture, but I want it to fit exactly in a A4 page with the margins I want. Keep in mind that that was just a MWE to illustrate the problem I was having. The end product will be much more complicated than that (and I have another problem there, which will be the subject of another question, whenever I get to it).

Comment: Sure.  Then you could remove the margins and draw an invisible A4 rectangle to get what you want.  Answer updated.